# How to query data based on specified Array field but constraint in security rules in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Just for example, I made rules like following(there's a field named **email**)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /collection/{documentId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.email in resource.data.email;
      //resource.data.email here is an Array!!!
    }
  }
}
```

But how to get any data through `where` query,I mean maybe like this:

```
 db.collection("store").where("id", "==", "1").onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    console.log("realtime---->", doc.data().cities);
                })
 })
```

Permission problem still exists...And the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query?authuser=0) shows that I'm supposed to include **the same constraint** as the rules defined above on the `email` field. How to deal with it in `Array` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,I finally found out that it's **impossible** to query through array because of the official documentation:https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays has already said about it.
what you can do is to make the `authenticated field` as an object,like

```
{
    hash1:1,
    hash2:0
}
```

the key-value pair can represent different users with different level of authority. 
   Make the rules like:

```
//here I set the hash as user uid, and query through carId
allow read,write:if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/car/$(resource.data.carId)).data.authfield[request.auth.uid]=="1"
```

Then,to query it through

```
db.collection("col1").where("carId","==","ABC").where("authfield.hash1","==","1")
```

By the way, the `hash1` field **cannot** be set as Email format or other formats with **dot** inside it, because it only recognizes the first **dot** as the separated symbol between object and its property.

For example, as for a field named "dou@company.com", if you put it in `where` query, it will consider it as in the object "dou@company",and read its property "com".